# Perl XML::LibXML - search & relace textContent

Tags: perl, xml-libxml

As the title says, I simply want to iterate over every text node and search & replace a value.  How can I do this using XML::LibXML?

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::LibXML qw(XML_ELEMENT_NODE XML_ATTRIBUTE_NODE XML_TEXT_NODE);

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new({keep_blanks => 0 });
my $dom = $parser->load_xml(location => 'walkDOM.xml') or die;

foreach my $fndval2 ($dom->findnodes('//*'))
{
 foreach my $child ( $fndval2->getChildnodes()) 
 {
  if ($child->nodeType eq 3)  **# still can't figure-out how to use keyword instead** 
  {
   **<<  right here I like to search/grep for value and replace >>**   
   print "NodeName: ", $fndval2->nodeName(), " VALUE: ", $child->textContent, "\n";
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Reguardng your comment, `$child->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE`. Sorry, no time to answer question at this time.

Comment: @ikegami ahhh, don't use single nor double quotes around XML_TEXT_NODE ... thank you!

Comment: If I add the following: 
   my $data = $child->getData();
   $data =~ s/$sv/$rv/gi;  #<-- $sv & $rv are previously defined
   $child->setData ($data);

But I can't use a $var for the matching modifiers ... hmmm e.g.
$data =~ s/$sv/$rv/$flag;
it says "Scalar found where operator expected ..."

Comment: Yeah, and `$t='t'; prin$t "foo";` doesn't work either. If you're going to generate code, you'll need `eval EXPR`, though in this case, you can use `s/(?$flag:$regexp)/$rv/`

Comment: @ikegami - thank you!  Yes, putting the matching modifiers as you suggest in front works fine.
s/(?$flag)$sv/$rv/g where $flag=i